# how to get jquery flexslider to auto play

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am trying to configure jquery.flexslider to auto play. By default it is set to scroll manually.

From what I have read this feature is available but I cant find where to set the action to auto play.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
if (!slider.playing) {
 slider.play();
}
```